# PHPFog Connecting with SSH

Tags: ssh, phpfog

I have a Github account set up on my mac using SSH. Now I want to set my PHPFog account with my mac using SSH, however I am unable to give it the correct SSH Key.

If I open up the SSH folder on my mac I see 2 files named `github_rsa` & `github_rsa.pub`. Opening the file named `github_rsa` shows a text file which contains somthing along the lines of

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
some-detail: 1
some-detail: 2

asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf
asdfasdfsadfasdfasdfadsfasdfasdf
asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfa
//goes on for a while

-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

If I try and copy and paste the code part into PHPFog it tells me its not valid. If I try pasting it into PHPFog with ssh-rsa at the top, it stills tells me its not a valid SSH key. I even tried generating a key however the result is a text file that looks just the same as above...

Can anyone tell me how to get the right SSH key to copy and paste into PHPFog. Preferable the same one I use for my Github account if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a different ssh key to give to PHP Fog. The following link has all the information you need.

http://docs.phpfog.com/getting-started/ssh/

You will need to submit the contents of the .pub file not the private key.